# Cron is not working in server but working in local

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, cron, job-scheduling

```
async startCronJob() {
    const { CRON_EXPRESS } = await this.retrieveEnvVarsService.get();
    this.logger.log(`Cron registered with this expression : ${CRON_EXPRESS}`);
    await cron.schedule(CRON_EXPRESS, async () => {
      this.logger.log('cronjob is firing');
     await this.firebase.sendPushNotificationBasedOnScenarios();
    });
  }
```

This piece of code is being used to send the push notification at some specific time, i have gone through log I am starting the cronjob but this cron.schedule is not getting triggered due to which the function sendPushNotificationBasedOnScenarios() is not getting called, the catch is its working properly in local but not in server, I am using AWS lambda function.